# XSLT filter XML documents that contains a specific letter

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, contains

I am new in XLST and I have an assignment to do.  I have to filtered a XML document so that only those elements whose names contain the letter "a" are included.

The result must contains the name of the element.  By example:

If I have the following XML:

```
    <?xml-stylesheet href="monfichier.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
    <a>
    <ab x="x"><b>Test</b><a>z</a></ab>
    <z x="x"><a>z</a></z>
    </a>
```

The result must be:

```
   <a>
   <ab x="x"><a>z</a></ab>
   </a>
```

How can I do this?  I try multiples ways to obtain the good result with `name(.)`, the contains function but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

you can first start with an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then, an override template that eliminates other nodes that do not contain an `a`

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(contains(name(), 'a'))]"/>
```

thus the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(contains(name(), 'a'))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```